# How to detect when an enter is pressed using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to detect what key is pressed and based on that I want to fire `click()` event.

My code work for all the key except for the enter.

for some reason when I press "enter" I do not get any messages on the screen as if the enter button was not pressed.

Here is my code

```
    $(function(){
        $(document).keypress(function(e) {
            handleKeyPress(e);
        });

        function handleKeyPress( e ){

            var key = e.which;

            alert(key);

            if( getIcwsTabIndex() != 1){
                return;
            }

            if( key >= 48 && key <= 57){
                var k = key - 48;
                $('#icwsDialerNumber' + k).click();
            }

            if( key == 8){
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#icwsDialerScreenDel').click();

            }

            if( key == 13){
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#icwsDialerNumberDial').click();
            }
        }
    });
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Running this code correctly gave me a 13 alert.  Are you seeing any errors in your javascript console?

Comment: no errors. I am using Firefox I don't know if that makes a difference

Comment: on`.keyup()` when `EventObject.keyCode === 13`.

Comment: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2gp01u98/) - try commenting out the `getIcwsTabIndex` function  -  are you sure this function isn't returning something other than 1?

Comment: FYI, I'm also getting the correct response.

Comment: Try `keyup` instead and see what happens.

Comment: @PHPglue  if you post your comment as an answer I will accept your answer as it did the trick. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

tested your code, it works on chrome besides the not defined getIcwsTabIndex

so verify it is ok on  your side

[here is a fiddle check the console](https://jsfiddle.net/6p4jLj8g/)

```
 $(function(){
        $(document).keypress(function(e) {
            handleKeyPress(e);
        });

        function handleKeyPress( e ){

            var key = e.which;
            console.log(key);


    //            if( getIcwsTabIndex() != 1){
    //                return;
    //            }

            if( key >= 48 && key <= 57){
                var k = key - 48;

                $('#icwsDialerNumber' + k).click();
            }

            if( key == 8){
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#icwsDialerScreenDel').click();

            }

            if( key == 13){
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log(key);
                $('#icwsDialerNumberDial').click();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I did that does not make a difference

Comment: as you can see in the jsfiddle the key prints to the console so - is the "#icwsDialerNumberDial" defined and does something registered to its click event ?

Answer (score -1):

The problem with your code is that is not cross-browser. It should be:

```
var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;
```

Comment: It's  jQuery. They figure for that.